# Is there any way to get IE8 to not ignore a CSS rule that it only partially understands?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I just ran into what seems like absurd behavior to me.  If IE8 doesn't understand part of a rule it ignores the entire thing:

```
input[type=radio]:checked,
input.checked {
    /* Some CSS */
}
```

I already have IE8 specific JS adding the `.checked` class, but because it doesn't understand `:checked`, it ignores the entire thing, so I'm forced to now have several rules:

```
input[type=radio]:checked{
    /* Some CSS */
}
input.checked {
    /* The exact same CSS */
}
```

So my question -- does anyone know of a way to get IE8 and below to ignore the `:checked` instead of throwing out the entire rule?

Very basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/8UT56/

Comment: What happens if the "understood" rule comes first? e.g. `input.checked, input[type=radio]:checked`?

Comment: It's not absurd behaviour. For once, IE8 is acting according to [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets): `the whole statement should be ignored if there is an error anywhere in the selector`. Not sure if there's a workaround though.

Comment: For the record, if you're going to add the `.checked` class anyway, you may as well do it for all browsers and do away with the browser detection and rule duplication mess.

Comment: @BoltClock - I don't remember exactly why I did this (it was 2 years ago), but IE fires `change` events on checkboxes at different times than other browsers, so it's sometimes just easier to deal with IE only instead of figuring out if `this.checked` in the `onChange` event means it _was_ checked or _is now_ checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library like http://selectivizr.com/ to give IE newer selectors.

Comment: Am I the only one to be bothered using JS to fix CSS?

Comment: Well, it's only for older browsers, and it does let you use just CSS for most people. I used to feel like that, but now I realise that HTML + CSS + JS is the platform, and that for most projects you already rely on all 3 to get the job done.

Comment: Keep in mind that while CSS can be downloaded and parsed in parallel, JS will not. If IE8 users are a big part of your user base consider doing this server-side.