# Radio Button CSS issue with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, radio-button

Friends can you help me solve this small issue please.
I am using opencart and my products require the buyer to chose color before add cart.

Normally we use LI with a href to make color boxex with onclick select even but Since Opencart allow only form elements for such requirements i.e. select, check, radio etc therefore i used Radio buttons with CSS.
It works fine on Mozilla, Chrome and even on IE9 .... BUT not on IE8 & IE7 :(

**here is the HTML of Radio buttons after compiled**

```
<div class="option Color" id="option-227">
<span class="required">*</span>
<h2>Color:</h2><br>

<div class="colorOption-Holder">
<input type="radio" id="option-value-18" value="18" name="option[227]">
<label for="option-value-18">
<img src="../images/Swatches/Green-25x25.gif" alt="Green" title="Green">
</label>
</div>

<div class="colorOption-Holder">
<input type="radio" id="option-value-18" value="18" name="option[227]">
<label for="option-value-18">
<img src="../images/Swatches/Blue-25x25.gif" alt="Blue" title="Blue">
</label>
</div>

</div>
```

**And here is the CSS**

```
.product-info .Color .colorOption-Holder {
float:left;
width:35px;
height:35px;
margin-right:7px;
margin-bottom:9px;
position:relative;
}
.product-info .Color input{
position:absolute;
left:5px;
top:10px;
visibility:hidden;
z-index:5;
}

.product-info .Color input + label {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;

border:1px solid #fff;
}

.product-info .Color input:checked + label {
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index:5;
border:1px solid #f76a02;
}
```

Any Idea how to fix this ?
it would be a big favor ... thanks

Comment: @MystereMan, that's true unless he's using an html5 doctype.  `input` tags no longer need the closing slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

internet explorer 8 (and previous versions) does not support many CSS selectors. the :checked pseudo class is one of them.

Check [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968867/is-there-any-way-to-get-ie8-to-not-ignore-a-css-rule-that-it-only-partially-unde) for a solution called [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) which allows you to add selectors support for different IE versions.

You should check [quirks-mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) for browser support of different selectors when you don't stick with the "usual" ones.

Comment: Thanks friend, i tried but it didnt work :( ...  <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/selectivizr.js"></script>
   <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
 <![endif]-->

Comment: I've never used it myself, but did you add one of the javascript libraries (like jQuery, dojo, mootools etc...)?
You need to add jQuery (for example) before using this, so it should look something like that:
`<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="selectivizr.js"></script>
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie-fallback.css" media="screen, projection"></noscript>
<![endif]--> 
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">`.

Comment: Also make sure your CSS loads using <link> not <style>@import</style> - Selectivizr doesn't work with @import.

Answer (score 0):

The closing tags are in codes but  i dont know why they are not showing here
here is the code from product/product.tpl file

```
<?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
<div class="colorOption-Holder">
<input type="radio" name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo  $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" />
<label for="option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $option_value['image']; ?>" />
 <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
(<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?>)
<?php } ?>
</label>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```